# How to use single widget with multiple providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, provider

1. My app is eCommerce store with dashboard has multiple lists: `LatestProducts`, `DiscountProducts`, `MostViewedProduct`, ...
2. I create Multi Providers: `LatestProductProvider`, `DiscountProductProvider`, `MostViewedProductProvider`
   (actually same providers with filter parameter that get different sorted products)
3. I don't want create multiple widget for each product list. My main widget reuses this single widget class:

   ```
    class _ProductsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
     const _ProductsWidget({ Key key, @required this.filter,}) : super(key: key);
     final String filter;

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      dynamic productProvider = null;
      if (filter == '0') productProvider = Provider.of<LatestProductProvider>(context);
      if (filter == '1') productProvider = Provider.of<DiscountProductProvider>(context);
      if (filter == '2') productProvider = Provider.of<MostViewedProductProvider>(context);
      return SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: ...
           ...
           //use matched productProvider
   ```

How to code above scenario?
When i test my codes, my lists load parallel datas. this image is my result:

[Result in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhC0s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Filter the Latest, Discounted and MostViewed products inside your model. You would then a storeproducts object.

```
class StoreProducts{
final List<Product> latest;
final List<Product> mostViewed;
final List<Product> discounted;
//if needed
final List<Product> otherProducts;

StoreProducts(this.latest,this.mostViewed,this.discounted);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you suggest I use One provider. But i want One Widget with multi provider model.